# CMake: How to hide symbols from a precompiled library

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I have a compiled library C++ (let's call it *a.so*) which have Boost library symbols linked in it and I don't have the source to recompile it.

I've made a C++ program which needs to link to both this library and the boost version installed on my computer.

But when my program try to reach Boost functions, it ends up calling Boost functions defined in *a.so* instead of the ones on my computer.

I've tried to make a wrapper library around *a.so* to hide unwanted symbols but it failed to compile.

How can I configure CMake to make it build and work, with or without wrapper ?

The solution needs to be Linux-compatible.

Comment: Have you tried linking the boost libraries dynamically instead of statically for your library a.so?

Comment: No because as mentionned I don't have the source to recompile it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`add_custom_command`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_custom_command.html), creating a `PRE_LINK` step, which removes the boost functions from `a.so`. You could either write it to a new file (and change which .so you link with in your CMake), or overwrite it.

This can be done with the [`objcopy`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/objcopy) utility and the `--strip-symbols` argument. Assuming there are a lot of boost symbols you'd like to strip, using `nm` on `a.so` and filtering the boost symbols into a file is probably prudent.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out.